# data["comment"].str.contains taking to much time

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have to do a pattern match for a column in my dataset and find the below matches for almost 400,000 rows.

It is taking a lot of time to execute. Is there a way to reduce run time or is there a better code for this which gives similar result in less time?

```
monthnames=data["comment"].str.contains("\\bJan\\b|\\bFeb\\b|\\bMar\\b|\\bApr\\ |\\bMay\\b|\\bJun\\b|\\bJul\\b|\\bAug\\b|\\bSep\\b|\\bOct\\b|\\bNov\\b|\\bDec\\b")
```

Comment: Time is relative, you need to give some more details.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Kindly suggest what detail is needed. I will try to give that.

Comment: James is asking for a precise length of time.  1 second? 1 minute? 1 hour? 1 day?  _long_ can mean a lot of things

Comment: I have an unrelated recommendation: it may be better to construct the pattern automatically with `"|".join(map("\\b{}\\b".format, calendar.month_abbr[1:]))`. As for the question itself, your solution is probably the optimal.

Comment: @JamesJenkins : The above just a sample code. In real , I have around 37 keywords which has to be matched. Its talking around 50-55~ seconds.

Comment: @DyZ : I will try and let you know.Anyway thank you so much..